# Array alternative when writing to Firebase iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nodes

Im Using swift- i know its not the best idea to save arrays to firebase. But i implemented already and ran into problems so i need to backtrack. Does any body have possible suggestions on how i can

This is how my array is currently saved in Firebase.

```
planits
 -LEQfNxgZZtg1qtlOzly
 dates
   0: "Jun 12, 2018 at 5:30 PM"
   1: "Jun 7, 2018 at 5:30 PM"
 images
   0: "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3
   1: "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3
 plans
   0: "SoulfulofNoise The Tour @ Pomona (CANCELLED)"
   1: "Just what you needed"
 senderId
   0: "ZjtJdkjzuxc0mZn4u9TfWsXa9jh2"
 title: "hey lets meet up"
```

This is my initializing function that will be called to send data to Firebase

```
    func uploadPlanit(withPlanTitle plans: [String], withPlanDate date: [String], withTitle title: String, forUID uid: [String], withImageStrings images: [String], sendComplete: @escaping (_ status: Bool) -> ()) {


        _REF_PLANITS.childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["plans": plans, "dates": date, "title": title, "senderId": uid, "images": images])
            sendComplete(true)



    }
```

This is a class within my app where i call this data function - As you can see - my problem is that i am passing in arrays to the function. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
 DataService.instance.uploadPlanit(withPlanTitle: FirstViewController.nameOfIndividualEvent as! [String], withPlanDate: FirstViewController.planDateLink as! [String], withTitle: nameOfPlanItTitle!, forUID: [(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!], withImageStrings: FirstViewController.planImageLinks as! [String])
```

EDIT_! I am trying to restructure it in this format

```
planits     
LE2DSLfkxN093N
         ZTOlj8EAFD
          dates: "Jun 12, 2018 at 5:30 PM"
          images: "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3
          plans:  "Just what you needed"
        ZTUL9UF93JF
          dates: "Jun 12, 2018 at 5:30 PM"
          images: ""https://img.evbuc.com/https%3
          plans: "SoulfulofNoise The Tour @ Pomona (CANCELLED)"
        title: "hey lets meet up"
```

[image]

Comment: What issue you are facing with this structure?

Comment: I can not delete, modify any of the data because Firebase will either delete the entire array; or the indices will be mixed up in some way. For instance; I would like to add a second “senderId” but when I update value; it deletes the previous value

Comment: It’s difficult to make changes to DB with the structure set up like that. I am attempting to rewrite it now in a more sensible way

Comment: It depends on table structure. What would you like to make primary key I mean  data will be based on which id? `planits` Id ?

Comment: Check the edited question right now i will show you the way i am trying to restructure it

Comment: @TheTiger i just updated now. Instead of original post where all "dates" were stored together, all "plans" were stored together & so on. It is better to store each plan, date and image in a pair, that way each one is grouped together.

Comment: By original post - i mean my very first question, before the edited question @TheTiger

Comment: Yes this is correct. Do you still have any issue?